# On VS Code on macOS, how to keep two projects open in macOS window tabs (instead of two windows)?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have VS Code 1.15.1 and when I work at two projects at once, I choose File -> New Window and open the second project. Clicking File -> New Window opens new window with VS Code. 
On my other computer (not sure about the VS Code version there), when I click File -> New Window, instead of opening new window, it will rather open new tab, so that I end up with two tabs in one window, each tab for one project and the active tab occupies whole screen estate.

Any ideas what should I change in Settings to achieve this "single window, multiple tabs" layout when having multiple projects?

I use macos (not sure if OS may be somehow related to the window management settings)

Answer (score 89):

1. Go to **Preferences** > **Settings**.
2. Search for `native tabs`
3. Check the checkbox

[image: Native tabs checkbox]

4. Code will prompt for restart to take effect.

[image: Dialog box prompt for restart]

5. After restart, make sure you have multiple projects open. And then merge all windows as shown below:

[image: Merge all windows]

6. Enjoy multiple tabs in single window.

Note: I think this applies to all Mac OS >= Sierra. Tested with Catalina, Big Sur, Ventura recently.

Comment: is there a way for this in windows? It's really troublesome to handle four projects like admin ui, admin api ,client ui and client api

Comment: In Sonoma I don't have the "Merge All Windows" option :(

Answer (score 32):

Just set in your user settings

`"window.nativeTabs": true`

and do Window -> Merge All Windows

note: If you have High Sierra installed, that might be an issue.

Here's the link:
[Better macOS native window tabs support](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_better-macos-native-window-tabs-support)

Comment: thank you for response Alex.. though I cannot currently verify if it works, because unfortunately I updated to High Sierra -- and as you properly warned me :) the native tabs don't work there.. just a grey horizontal stripe is displayed where the tabs should be.

Comment: In Sonoma I don't have the "Merge All Windows" option :(

Answer (score 9):

In Mac OS, there is a system setting outside of VS Code.  Set this and then opening files/folders from the command line will also automatically open the file/folder in a new tab instead of a new window.

In MacOS 12.3 (Monterrey) this is under:

- System Preferences > General > Prefer tabs ____ when opening documents.

Change this setting to **always**.  (The default is **in full
screen**).

You might additionally need to set the setting in VS Code `"window.nativeTabs": true` as the other commenters have already suggested.

Comment: On ventura is shown at System Preferences > Desktop & Dock > Windows & Apps

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vscode 1.81.1, and you just need to go to settings -> window.
Check the Native Tabs (Applies to all profiles).
It will prompt for a restart, do that and you're good to go

Comment: what does this add to the existing top answers?

Answer (score -1):

Setting For MAC OS (Ventura V13.1):

[Click on code > Settings > settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8380.png)

Find option:
**native tabs**

[Enable and restart VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOWTM.png)

Comment: In Sonoma it is not enough

Comment: @NisimNaim,

Can you please add your configuration in the comment If I missed any?

Comment: Aniruddha Mirajkar I have MacOS Sonoma and VS Code Version: 1.86.1. It doesn't work for me. I also don't have the Merge All Windows options that other answers suggested to use.

Comment: @NisimNaim ,

i changed my answer I added the MAC OS version.