# How to set Merge All Windows as default in VS Code on macOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I've found this useful help to Merge All Windows in Visual Studio Code:

[VS Code: how to keep two projects open in tabs (instead of two windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916181/vs-code-how-to-keep-two-projects-open-in-tabs-instead-of-two-windows)

Now I'd need:

- to set as default on Visual Studio Code startup
- and to Merge automatically when I open a new Window (when I press Shift+Command+N).

I've only found the shortcut Command+M on MacOS to Merge the Windows. This is good, but it would be better to make it work automatically since I have a lot of projects to close and open at the same time.

Comment: with the `runCommands` command you can bind a sequence of commands to a key press, find the command id's you want to combine

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the first part of your question, that should already be handled by `"window.nativeTabs": true` in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

I don't know how to do the rest of what you're asking. But there are a number of things to make this easier on yourself.

- You can use the command that opens a new window tab instead of a new window: `workbench.action.newWindowTab`.
- You can keep opening new windows instead of new window tabs, and then bind to the command that merges windows: `workbench.action.mergeAllWindowTabs`.

If they don't have shortcuts bound to them by default, you can [create shortcuts yourself](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

---

Okay, actually, I kind of lied.

> to Merge automatically when I open a new Window (when I press Shift+Command+N)

I know how achieve the same effect without actually doing it exactly how you described: Unbind the default new window keyboard shortcut and bind `workbench.action.newWindowTab` to that key instead. Ex. (in keybindings.json)

```json
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+n",
    "command": "-workbench.action.newWindow"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+n",
    "command": "workbench.action.newWindowTab",
},
```

To see other commands related to window tabs, open the command palette and search "window tab", or the keyboard shortcut editor and search "window tab".

---

Some (closed,) related issue tickets:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116343
- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18138

  - https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/40529